# Symfony installation Error: curl: (35) SSL peer handshake failed, the server most likely requires a client certificate to connect

Tags: curl, symfony

I wanted to install Symfony 3.0 on my Mac Os, using the following commands:

```
$ sudo curl -LsS https://symfony.com/installer -o /usr/local/bin/symfony
$ sudo chmod a+x /usr/local/bin/symfony
```

Got the following error:

```
curl: (35) SSL peer handshake failed, the server most likely requires a client certificate to connect
```

Any solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Partially found a solution, supposing you have installed Homebrew on your mac
You can download installer file using

```
$wget https://symfony.com/installer
```

and put it in this directory:

```
$mv installer /usr/local/bin/symfony
```

By changing the name from installer to symfony, and then execute:

```
$sudo chmod a+x /usr/local/bin/symfony
$source .bash_profile
```

However, I don't know what to do to make it automatically as it is supposed to be.